# ssas 2005 calculation between two measure group

Tags: ssas

I am new to SSAS. E.g.I have a sales measure group, with one measure: amount (aggregate function: sum) . Also another measure group sales 1 with one measure: transactions (aggregate function:DistinctCount). now I need to calculate average amount per transaction, so it should be amount/transactions. How can I do that? Is it calculated member in cube designer - calculation tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a calculated measure. To do this, open the "Calculations" tab of the cube editor. Then click on the calculator button in the tool bar, which opens the "Calculated Member" editor. Fill the fields, at least name and expression, possibly format string, associated measure group, and/or display folder as well, and deploy the cube. The expression should be something like

```
[Measures].[Amount] / [Measures].[Transactions]
```

You can drag and drop items from the bottom left into the expression if you are unsure about the naming conventions. The slash (for division) of the expression you will have to enter manually.